# Adding google analytics to Laravel / Inertia / Vue application

Tags: laravel, vue.js, google-analytics, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm using Laravel with Inerta and Vue and I wounder how can I add google analytics to all pages?

This is my main.js code:

```
/* eslint-disable import/order */
import '@/@iconify/icons-bundle'
import layoutsPlugin from '@/plugins/layouts'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'
import VueToast from 'vue-toast-notification'
import 'vue-toast-notification/dist/theme-default.css'
import { createInertiaApp, Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers'
import { loadFonts } from '@/plugins/webfontloader'
import './../styles/@core/template/index.scss'
import '@styles/styles.scss'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m'
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'

loadFonts()
createInertiaApp({
    title: title => `${title}`,
    resolve: name => resolvePageComponent(`./pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line vue/component-api-style
        const vueApp = createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })

        vueApp.use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .use(VueToast, {
                position: 'top',
                pauseOnHover: true,
            }).provide('toast', vueApp.config.globalProperties.$toast)
            .use(vuetify)
            .use(createPinia())
            .use(layoutsPlugin)
            .use(Link)
            .mount(el)

        return vueApp
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to paste the snipped code of Google Tag in  section of all of your pages.
[GA docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9304153?hl=en#zippy=%2Cweb%2Cadd-the-google-tag-directly-to-your-web-pages)

Comment: To every single template file? or to layouts only?

Comment: In your case (Vue or Nuxt) you could put tag in layout, within <head> **BUT** remember, that since Vue is an SPA application and layout is not reloading, just displaying different views. That makes a problem with tracking information about users on you page.
There is a good and quick solution, a plugin called vue-gtag. It helps implementing and tracking information across the page.
There was previously a plugin called vue-analytics but it's no longer supported.
Check in docs "AutoTracking" to see how to track all views with vue-router.
[link]https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/